# Space before and after \itemize

Tags: itemize, overleaf

I am writing my education section in CV:

```
 {\bf XYZi } \hfill
 {2018-2021} 
\\{ \textit {{LOL}}}\\
{ {{Cumulative Grade Point Average (CGPA) of 9.4 on a scale of 10.0: \begin{itemize}
[leftmargin=*,label=$\bullet$,noitemsep,partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
    \item A+ in the first year
    \item A+ in the second year
    \end{itemize}}
}
```

Now I am getting spaces like:

[image: SEE PICTURE]

I want to remove these top and bottom spaces between "Cumulative Grade point..." and items.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You may load `enumitem` and use  `\begin{itemize}[nosep]`.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the screenshot you provided with just the code you show. To the contrary, when I compile your code (using the `article` document class and loading the `enumitem` package) I get no gap above the `itemize` list. Please tell us more about your document setup.

Comment: @Bernard - The OP's code strongly suggests that he/she is employing the `enumitem` package. I agree with you that `noitemsep,partopsep=0pt,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt` may -- indeed, should! -- be replaced with `nosep`. Either way, there's a bigger issue: the OP's code doesn't seem capable of generating the associated screenshot.

Comment: Off-topic: You may want to replace `label=$\bullet$` with `label=\textbullet`.

Comment: @Mico: I must say I didn't have time to test, and I overlooked the code. B.t.w. why specify the label when one wants the default?

Comment: @Bernard - About the label: I can only guess that the OP (a) uses a document class that modifies the default label of level-1 `itemize` lists and (b) wishes to get back to the LaTeX default. Of course, this guess is just a guess.